# Multistep form with squarespace

Tags: forms, squarespace

I am trying to build a form with squarespace.

Form should have multiple steps and be in modal (overlay). After form is filled, there is a JSON with list of items, which should be filtered against criteria for the form and displayed.

Is it possible to do so with squarespace?